# Wordpress: authors page with custom query

Tags: wordpress

On a wordpress site I am coding an authors page. Therefore I use a custom query that I also use in several other parts of the site. Partly it works fine, but as it has a major bug, I cannot use it:

I receive not only a chosen autors post. All posts of all authors are listet.

If I use the main loop, I do not have that problem. But because of the pagination which should be the same everywhere, I would like to use the custom loop. Where is my mistake?

Here my code:

```
<?php 
        $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    ?>


        <section class="tk_fullwidth">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <h1 class="page-title">Beiträge von: <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h1>      

            <div id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                <div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 285, "gutter": 20 }'>


                <?php
                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                    $query = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type'   => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',  
                        'posts_per_page'         => '50',
                        'paged'                 => $paged,
                        'order'                  => 'DESC',
                        'orderby'                => 'date',
                    ) );
                ?>


                <!-- begin loop -->
                        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>


                   <div class="grid-item">
                        <a class="xyz" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                        <h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                        <?php 
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail('medium');
                            } 
                        ?>
                    </div><!-- grid-item -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- end loop -->


                <div class="tk_pagination">
                    <?php 
                        echo paginate_links( array(
                            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                            'show_all'     => false,
                            'type'         => 'plain',
                            'end_size'     => 2,
                            'mid_size'     => 1,
                            'prev_next'    => true,
                            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( '<', 'text-domain' ) ),
                            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( '>', 'text-domain' ) ),
                            'add_args'     => false,
                            'add_fragment' => '',
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </div>

                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                    <?php else : ?>
                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>


                </div>
            </div><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
    </section><!--tk_fullwidth-->
```

Comment: Are you saying that `$query` should only return posts by one specific author?

Comment: Yes and now. If I do it like that, that I define the author in the query, I will have to create a new templates: one for each author. That is a possibility, but in that case there are about 20 autors, so that will be complicated.

I would like to user´the "normal" authors site" (usually author.php). The problem here is that this site always uses the main query. But I would like to use my query and also my pagination. I suppose that must be possible. (?)

Comment: So where is your code going?

Comment: I dont understand. All I want is a coding-example for an authors page that uses a custom query. But I only see coding examples that use the main query.

Comment: Just add a custom query in template author.php and make your own loop. what is the problem?